# Unable to push to Google Container Registry - Bad request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

Having a problem with pushing to "gcr.io" or "us.gcr.io":

```
[]# gcloud docker --authorize only
Short-lived access for ['gcr.io', 'us.gcr.io', 'eu.gcr.io', 'asia.gcr.io', 'b.gcr.io', 'bucket.gcr.io', 'appengine.gcr.io'] configured.

[]# docker push gcr.io/tre-dock/pytest
e817ce2379ed: Retrying in 1 seconds
c543d14fcca9: Retrying in 1 seconds
a147e49918ce: Retrying in 3 seconds
063ca6c7c6e9: Retrying in 5 seconds
8f045733649f: Retrying in 7 seconds
unknown: Bad Request.
```

Yet when I try to push to "b.gcr.io" - everything seems to work.

What do I miss?

Environment:

```
[]# gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 101.0.0

alpha 2016.01.12
beta 2016.01.12
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2016.03.11
core-nix 2016.02.05
gcloud
gsutil 4.17
gsutil-nix 4.15
kubectl
kubectl-darwin-x86_64 1.1.7
```

Comment: For anyone copy/pasting here, it's --authorize-only not --authorize only

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was that the tag has to contain the project name:

```
gcr.io/project_name/tre-dock/pytest
```

Comment: That's correct. GCR assumes the first element after the hostname is the project ID:
gcr.io/$PROJECT_NAME/foo/bar:baz

The format: b.gcr.io instructs GCR to look for a storage bucket instead of using the project name:
b.gcr.io/$BUCKET_NAME/foo/bar:baz

Comment: Just to clarify, it should be project *ID* or project *name*? Those seem to be different in my case. The project name is the name I gave it and the project ID is the project name with a number appended.